# Pass Shell Command from WSL to Windows Host

Tags: linux, command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I would like to execute a shell command from WSL on my Windows host machine. Specifically, I would like to execute the command `qemu-system-i386 -s -S -fda out/floppy.img` since I'm building a piece of software and I would like to run this command using a Makefile in order to display the output.

Simply, I would like to invoke shell commands on my host machine from within the virtual machine; contrary to how you are able to invoke commands from the host to the VM using something like `wsl <command>`. I hope my explanation of what I'm trying to do was clear enough. I was not able to find anything online so I am asking here.

Is this possible?

Comment: I am not familiar with your command so I don't know if the following will work or not but it may help. `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/filesystems`. Go halfway done the page to `Run Windows tools from Linux` to see if it helps. Pay attention to the line: `Windows tools must include the file extension, match the file case, and be executable` in the article.

Comment: @Brian Thank you, this worked. As mentioned on the page, being specific by adding the file extension and noting the casing is crucial to making it work.

Comment: @Brian - you should post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/filesystems to see the solution. I have copied the section relevant to this specific question below.

---

**Run Windows tools from Linux**

WSL can run Windows tools directly from the WSL command line using [tool-name].exe. For example, notepad.exe.

Applications run this way have the following properties:

- Retain the working directory as the WSL command prompt (for the most part -- exceptions are explained below).
- Have the same permission rights as the WSL process.
- Run as the active Windows user.
- Appear in the Windows Task Manager as if directly executed from the CMD prompt.
  Windows executables run in WSL are handled similarly to native Linux executables -- piping, redirects, and even backgrounding work as expected.

To run the Windows tool ipconfig.exe, use the Linux tool grep to filter the "IPv4" results, and use the Linux tool cut to remove the column fields, from a Linux distribution (for example, Ubuntu) enter:

```
Bash

ipconfig.exe | grep IPv4 | cut -d: -f2
```

Let's try an example mixing Windows and Linux commands. Open your Linux distribution (ie. Ubuntu) and create a text file: touch foo.txt. Now use the Linux command ls -la to list the direct files and their creation details, plus the Windows PowerShell tool findstr.exe to filter the results so only your foo.txt file shows in the results:

```
Bash

ls -la | findstr.exe foo.txt
```

***Windows tools must include the file extension, match the file case, and be executable. Non-executables including batch scripts. CMD native commands like dir can be run with cmd.exe /C command.***

For example, list the contents of your Windows files system C:\ directory, by entering:

```
Bash

cmd.exe /C dir
```

Or use the ping command to send an echo request to the microsoft.com website:

```
Bash

ping.exe www.microsoft.com
```

Parameters are passed to the Windows binary unmodified. As an example, the following command will open C:\temp\foo.txt in notepad.exe:

```
Bash

notepad.exe "C:\temp\foo.txt"
```

This will also work:

```
Bash

notepad.exe C:\\temp\\foo.txt
```